# How mode of operation will be decided in SPI protocol?

Tags: linux-device-driver, mode, spi, baud-rate

How mode of operation will be decided in SPI protocol?
- I read that there are four mode of operations available in SPI Communication(Mode - 0, 1, 2, 3), so when we do any device interfacing using SPI Protocol how to decide which mode we should configure, is it the data available in sheet given by vendor companies that you should use ___ mode while do interfacing with this device? 
And also(same question as above for) baud rate at which Master and Slave will communicate?

Comment: It's set by an actual slave device in use.See `struct spi_device`, member `mode` for the details. `git grep` is your magician here.

Answer (score 1):

Both of supported mode and frequency is provided by vendor. If you'r selected mode don't match to that provided by vendor then there is strong chances of missing some bits(either MSB or LSB depending on the mismatch).